# Selector :first Error with For Loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, for-loop

A user specifies a numerical value; then a for loop runs it that many times. I have a series of these types of set ups, and they all work, except this one. I believe it's because of the :first selector I've used.

```
    jQuery.fn.removeX = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < xTimes; i++) {
            $("#Tell").append(' removed!');
            $("#List_" + C_user + " img:first").relocate();
        }
    }
```

I've tried variations, such as :nth-child(0), even .slice(), but so far nothing works. However, the .relocate function, it's designed only to handle one element at a time. I didn't think should make a difference, but if I switch it out for something like .appendTo, it works fine.

The .relocate script:

```
    jQuery.fn.relocate = function(){
        getSRC2 = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $(this).prependTo(".List_" + Owner).removeAttr('style');
        $(this).remove();
    }
```

It's nothing special, so I'm not sure how it breaks the other one.

Any tips/pointers would be helpful.

*SOLUTION*

Removed the .find(), worked, thanks! I was trying to reuse the script, but the objects it was originally designed for are wrapped, hence the .find().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you're selecting an `img`...

```
$("#List_" + C_user + " img:first").relocate();
```

Then in `.relocate()`, you're doing a `.find()` on the `img`...

```
getSRC2 = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
```

An `img` can't be nested inside an `img`.

---

Either get rid of the `.find('img')` since you already have it, or get rid of the `img` part of the selector...

```
$("#List_" + C_user).relocate();
```